# Свойство правостороннего связывания

Tags: pascal

Какая арифметическаяя операция (отсутсвующая в языке Турбо Паскаль) должна иметь свойство правостороннего связывания?

Comment: нече себе вопрос =) а для простых смертных можно его переформулировать?

Comment: хз, я только учусь)

Comment: скажи, что ты хочешь сделать, и мы скажем, как это надо сделать.

Comment: не, это контрольные вопросы по самоучителю, хочу полностью усвоить материал

Comment: похоже на что-то связанное с парсингом, но сформулировано как-то непонятно, если ты знаешь "такую операцию, которая нету в паскале" скажи какая она и где она есть, тогда скажем аналог или чем можно заменить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возведение в степень.

Comment: Спасибо, а можешь разъяснить суть ответа вообще?

Comment: Нет в паскале такой функции просто.

можно свою написать. допустим в цикле умножать число несколько раз.

Comment: Спасибо. Это я понял, но меня интересует процесс правостороннего связывания. Я не могу себе представить, как происходит этот процесс.

Comment: что за правостороннее связывание?

Comment: Из вопроса, мне и самому интересно, что это такое.

Comment: Наверное имеется в виду, что возведение в степень - [правоассоциативная](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ассоциативность) операция, т.е. a^b^c^d^e = a^(b^(c^(d^e)))

Comment: Большое спасибо всем, разобрался! Скажите, а вопрос удаляется или остается на форуме навсегда? Вроде нужно 250 очков репутации иметь чтобы вопрос закрыть.